# Parse endpoint to username/password

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I am trying to get my JSON from my Parse backend using my browser instead of my iOS app (for testing).

The url is:

https://api.parse.com/1/users/R7zHr4iu4M

but it requesting some more information (username and password).

I've tried my Parse personal account at it didn't work.

I've tried my `X-Parse-Application-Id` as username and my `X-Parse-REST-API-Key` as passowrd and it didn't work.

My endpoint parameters are:

- key  String  "X-Parse-Session-Token"
- key  String  "X-Parse-REST-API-Key"
- key  String  "X-Parse-Application-Id"

parameter encoding: URL

method: GET

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get your user's info you have to put

username: `application id`

password: `master key`

you can find it here.

[image]

Comment: Where can I ding the master key?